# Compatibility Belkin N1 Wireless Express card (F5D8071)

Tags: wifi

It seems that my Belkin N1 Wireless Express card (F5D8071) is not compatible with Elementary OS. For Ubuntu there seems to be an experimental driver: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_checkout_and_install_madwifi_experimental_driver_for_ar5008

Will this be supported?

Kind regards,

Tijmen

Answer (score 1):

The MadWifi driver has long been depreciated. It is however likely that the same install instructions in your link will work for elementary OS. It is also possible that your card is supported by either the ath5k or ath9k driver included with elementary OS. As expresscard34 devices can sometimes be handled by either the PCI or alternatively the USB bus can you give us the output of both `lspci` and `lsusb` and `lshw -c network`. Also anything from the `dmesg` command related to *ath0* or *wlan0*.